# Specify pattern and color for barplot with stacked and side by side bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a data set with average catch during the spawning season and entire year for 3 species of bass and 3 tournament size categories. I've created a barplot with bars grouped by species with side by side bars for `tourn_size` and stacked bars for spawning season (`spwn_seas`). However, The color scale I specified is being applied to `spwn_seas` rather than `tourn_size` as I would like. I've tried including `geom_col_pattern` and specifying `pattern = spawn_seas` but this puts large bars over top of the side by side bars. I want to have the stacked bars differentiated by some sort of pattern and the side by side bars to be separated by color.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Thanks in advance

Data

```
dat <- structure(list(tourn_size = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), levels = c("large", 
"medium", "small"), class = "factor"), species = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), levels = c("LMB", "SMB", "SPB"), class = "factor"), avg_ct = c(271.11, 
75.34, 40.34, 143.7, 22.57, 13.87, 146.51, 28.16, 9.78, 79.4, 
9.98, 6.07, 65.03, 5.85, 4, 49.27, 6, 2.55), se_ct = c(36.1178608723154, 
16.0247011556227, 6.65340977568233, 17.4416197842383, 3.76810488676504, 
3.20564495405438, 14.5250232265193, 4.06813014482874, 1.70440450439083, 
17.2573616830054, 2.83118791322653, 1.78108198132302, 12.305061378456, 
1.19436640643818, 1.1353687941798, 8.1598976675117, 1.23188390640916, 
0.687362936907718), lower_ct = c(234.992139127685, 59.3152988443773, 
33.6865902243177, 126.258380215762, 18.801895113235, 10.6643550459456, 
131.984976773481, 24.0918698551713, 8.07559549560917, 62.1426383169946, 
7.14881208677347, 4.28891801867698, 52.724938621544, 4.65563359356182, 
2.8646312058202, 41.1101023324883, 4.76811609359084, 1.86263706309228
), upper_ct = c(307.227860872315, 91.3647011556227, 46.9934097756823, 
161.141619784238, 26.338104886765, 17.0756449540544, 161.035023226519, 
32.2281301448287, 11.4844045043908, 96.6573616830054, 12.8111879132265, 
7.85108198132302, 77.335061378456, 7.04436640643817, 5.1353687941798, 
57.4298976675117, 7.23188390640916, 3.23736293690772), spwn_seas = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), levels = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-18L), class = "data.frame")
```

Barplot code

```
test_bar <- ggplot(data = dat, aes(x = species, y = avg_ct,
                                     group = tourn_size, 
                                     fill = spwn_seas,
                                     colour = tourn_size)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.4, end = 0.8) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,430,60),
                     labels = seq(0,430,60),
                     limits = c(0,430)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(x = species, ymin=lower_ct, ymax=upper_ct),
                position=position_dodge())

test_bar
```

[image]

Comment: You have `colour = tourn_size` but then you use `fill` scale. If you want a grey colour scale for `tourn_size`, use `scale_colour_grey`, not `scale_fill_grey`.

Comment: that seems to of just changed the error bar and outline color for bars, the fill is now different color but I still cannot add a pattern for spawn_seas? sorry if I'm missing something simple I'm not great with ggplot.